# related to forcing metacharecter as normal character in RegEx

Tags: java, regex

In oracle documentation the below statement is there.

metachatecters are `<([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>`

```
There are two ways to force a metacharacter to be treated as an ordinary character:

    * precede the metacharacter with a backslash, or
    * enclose it within \Q (which starts the quote) and \E (which ends it).
```

first way i understood.

Can any one explain about second way in details ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> * enclose it within \Q (which starts the quote) and \E (which ends it).
> ```

consider metacharacter `$` and now you want this to be  treated as a normal character, using 2nd way you have to enclose `$` between `\Q` and `\E` like below:

```
 "\\Q$\\E" (eqvivalent to `\\$`)
```

Note that however, you still have to escape `\Q` and `\E` with extra backslashes as they are not valid escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special method Pattern.quote(String). This is what it basically does internally

```
    int slashEIndex = s.indexOf("\\E");
    if (slashEIndex == -1)
        return "\\Q" + s + "\\E";
```

and if the string contains `"\\E"` sequences it will escape them